# How does MySQL handles GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate, mysql-8.0, mysql-workbench

I'm on Windows 10, MySQL Workbench. I'm on MySQL 8.0.

Here's the dataset. northwind.sql.

https://pastebin.com/bMgjXvfT

Objective:
**Write a query to get the order ID, customer's name, grand total of each order, and the name of the employee who handled each order. See below the expected first four rows.**

Output should look like this.

[image]
This is the database schema diagram.

https://brucebauer.info/assets/ITEC3610/Northwind/Northwind-Sample-Database-Diagram.pdf

It's northwind.sql database.

This is my query.

```
SELECT 
    o.orderid,
    c.contactname,
    SUM(od.unitprice * od.quantity),
    CONCAT(e.lastname, ' ', e.firstname) AS emp_name
FROM
    orders o
        INNER JOIN
    customers c ON o.customerid = c.customerid
        INNER JOIN
    orderdetails od ON o.orderid = od.OrderID
        INNER JOIN
    employees e ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
GROUP BY emp_name
ORDER BY orderid
LIMIT 4;
```

But it was producing an error.

**Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'northwind.o.OrderID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

But if I order by orderid alone, it'll work, Why does it work? Should not it be producing the same error as above?

Comment: *Is there a way I can permanently disable sql_mode=only_full_group_by?* Formally this is possible. But this is not correct solution. You must backwardly to edit your queries and make them correct.

Comment: ref [Why should not disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824498/why-should-not-disable-only-full-group-by/64831540#64831540),

Comment: If a column not mentioned in GROUP BY is not aggregated: case 1 - all rows in a group have the same value in this column, simply add it to GORUP BY expression; case2 - there are differrent values in this column, w/o only_full_group_by some **indefinite** one of them will be returned, and in this case you do not need in this column value at all, so remove it from the output list. As a palliative you may use special aggregate function ANY_VALUE().

Comment: @Akina can you explain a bit more, It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Start with basics, `GROUP BY x` will create a set of rows in which `x` is unique. The columns beside `x` in the rows of the result will be a single value. The other column results are the values listed in the first part of the select query. If by table structures, notably *not by the data* in the tables, the other result columns can only be a single value, it will be used. If its at all possible that multiple values of another column exist for `x`, and invalid aggregation error occurs. This can be rectified by applying a aggregate function over the value, and the function reduces the multiple values to a single value.

`GROUP BY emp_name` - if an employee handles more than one order, with the result set as `o.orderid`, isn't an aggregate expression. Group by `emp_name` means there will be one `emp_name` row in the result. With the possibility of more than one order for `emp_name`, without an aggregate expression over it, there cannot be one `emp_name` row and multiple orders with the same `emp_name`. If any employee handled more than one row, what would the column be? The answer is there's no defined value because the query cannot aggregate them into a single value.

`GROUP BY orderid`, regardless of which one (they are equivalent due to `[inner] join`), is a good aggregation and the best way for the query. `orderid` is the primary key of `o`/`orders` and therefore unique (like all primary keys).

- When joined on `employees` its on `EmployeeID`, the PK, so there will only be one employee per `orderid`, so there will always be one employee per order id in the result set and any `employee` columns can appear in the result.
- When joined on `customers`, by `customerid`, like `employees`, `cutomerid` is uniue, so there will be only one customer for the `orderid` and therefore any `customer` table columns can be in the result.
- When joined on `orderdetails`, multiple results per `orderid` are possible, however `orderdetails.{quantity,unitcost}` go through the aggregate function `sum`; so a single result occurs for `orderid` can is computed, and it can fit into a single value in the single row output for `orderid`.

Also be careful on `group by {expression}`. Even on the situation here `emp_name`, based on structure (not data), isn't defined as unique in the same way as `EmployeeID`. The unique relation between `EmployeeID` can be seen, but `emp_name` isn't necessary unique in `employees`.

Comment: >GROUP BY emp_name - obviously invalid, what if an employee handles more than one order.

I don't understand what'd be wrong with this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: >When joined on orderdetails, multiple entries are possible, however these go through the aggregate function sum so a single result occurs.
How? I don't understand. It's joined on orderid which is a primary key as well.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: 1) Is it necessary that expression in group by(expression) should be unique?
2) I didn't understand what you were trying to potray by those 3 bulleted points! Could you clarify. By now, I understand that if there are 2 orders with same emp_name, since order isn't aggregated which  order would you take and that'd produce meaningless query. But how do I figure that beforehand? A framework to think?